# Why getting too many rerenders in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, use-effect, use-state

I have the following code in React to get data from Firebase. I am new to `useEffect` and it is giving too many rerenders error:

```
let post1 = [];
useEffect(() => {
  getDocs(collection(db, "posts")).then((snapshot) => {
    const data = snapshot.docs.map((doc) => ({
      id: doc.id,
      ...doc.data(),
    }));
    post1 = data;
  })
}, [posts]);
setPosts(post1);
```

Comment: `post1` and the `setPosts()` call should go inside the `getDocs` then callback

Comment: `setPosts` is outside the useEffect so it is called on every re-render, and since it updates the state, it also causes a re-rerender

Comment: and remove `posts` from the useEffect dependencies else you will get a loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you wrote it, `setPosts(post1)` is being called on every render. I'm assuming `posts` and `setPosts` are destructured from a `useState()` value which means that every time you call `setPosts()`, it triggers a rerender. You need to move the `setPosts()` call to the `useEffect()`. You also need to remove `posts` from the dependency array of `useEffect` because if any of those dependencies change, it triggers a rerender as well. In your specific case, try this:

```
useEffect(() => {
  getDocs(collection(db, "posts")).then((snapshot) => {
    const data = snapshot.docs.map((doc) => ({
      id: doc.id,
      ...doc.data(),
    }));
    setPosts(data);
  })
}, []);
```

Comment: setPosts(data) will trigger a rerender because posts is a dependency in ... } [posts]), this does not solves the problem